# How to extract .arc files

Tags: macos, compression

I downloaded a software from the internet which is in .arc format. How can I extract the files on MAC?

The arc file is 4GB, but I believe it will be 30 GB when extracted.

Answer (score 5):

There's a great, free, Mac app called The Unarchiver that has extracted every archive I've ever thrown at it. The [supported formats](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/formats) page says it will extract ARC files as well.

The Unarchiver [homepage](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/unarchiver)
The Unarchiver on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12&ls=1)

Comment: The Unarchiver for mac doesn't work on .arc files.

Comment: The above comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The Unarchiver has been acquired by [MacPaw](https://macpaw.com) and is available for free [download](https://macpaw.com/the-unarchiver). I just downloaded it and used it to successfully unarchive an ARC archive from 1988. I'm running it on macOS High Sierra (v10.13.5), but it should run on anything since macOS 10.7--and MacPaw even has legacy versions available. The Unarchiver lists 60 different archive formats in its preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com)
- [StuffIt Expander](https://my.smithmicro.com/stuffit-expander-mac.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the windows binary release here (through wine): https://sourceforge.net/projects/freearc, or try to compile it for macOS (modification of source file to use macOS headers and libraries are needed).